# How to share a Google CSE results element with two different types of search elements

Tags: javascript, html, google-custom-search

High level the goal is to have a "search" page with "two-column" Google CSE (API 2.0) search and result elements and have "two page" search elements on other pages that display results on the "search" page.  This would seem to say two different types of result elements would be needed on the "search" page.

Should the design be to share the "search" page result element between the "two column" and "two page" search elements or have two different result elements?

Conceptually, if you could determine if the results were coming from the "two column" element or one of the "two page" elements you could use a callback (starting?) to configure the result element to match the search.  Once the search page has been used to display the "two page" results, it would need to be able to display "two column" results from searches on that page.

1. Would it be better to have two different result elements and have a callback (rendered?) hide the unused one or would it be better to dynamically configure a single result element?
2. If a single result element is used, how can the source of the results ("two column" or "two page" search) be determined in a callback?
3. Can a callback customize a result element multiple times after a page is loaded?
4. Would there be any issues with gname and result element customization?

Answer (score 0):

An experiment found something that seems to work, but it is not explained by the Google documentation.  The experiment has two (2) pages: Search1.htm & Serach2.htm.

Search1.htm

```
<body>
  <h1>Search1.htm</h1>
  <h2>Two Page Search</h2>
  <div class="gcse-searchbox-only" data-gname="page" data-resultsUrl=”Search2.htm"></div>
</body>
```

Search2.htm

```
<body>
  <h1>Search2.htm</h1>
  <h2>Two Column Search</h2>
  <div class="gcse-searchbox" data-gname="column"></div>
  <h2>Two Column Results</h2>
  <div class="gcse-searchresults" data-gname="column"></div>
  <h2>Two Page Results</h2>
  <div class="gcse-searchresults-only" data-gname="page"></div>
</body>
```

A search from Search1.htm generates results into both Search2.htm result elements.  Using callbacks, all callbacks for both gnames (page & column) were driven with the same results.  A search using Search2.htm places results only in the gname=”column” element.

Removing the Search2.htm gname="page" element resulted in the desired behavior where searches from Search1.htm and Search2.htm shared the same results element.  This not described in the Google documentation, but seems to be a simple solution.

Additionally, testing did not seem to find any information, available in the various callbacks (initilaizationCallback, starting, ready & rendered) what would indicate which search element was providing results.